# Where should I post a question regarding the "whois" and "dnslookup" utilities?

Tags: discussion, support, site-recommendation

I have a question regarding the `whois` and `dnslookup` utilities and how to interpret their output. Where should I post my question please?

Comment: Sounds like a job for [SuperUser](http://superuser.com) (super hero reference intended)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like a job for **[SuperUser](https://superuser.com/)**!!

From their FAQ:

> If you have a question about …
>
> - computer hardware,
> - computer software, or
> - personal and home computer networking

Your questions falls into 2 and 3.

Comment: -1 for not taking my Super Hero reference! ;-)

Comment: @AndrewBarber: [meta-tag:status-completed]

Comment: Was about to downvote for stealing the super-hero reference, then read comments...

Comment: @meagar Hmm... good thing I didn't just delete my comment, then! hehe